# syntax error on line: `if x.isupper() and not in y`

Tags: python

I'm getting "invalid syntax" errors pointing to the "in" statement. What's my mistake?

```
while(notes > 1):
    note = choice(scale)
    if note[0].isupper() and not in patternNotes:
        patternNotes.append(note)
        notes -= 1

    elif note is not rootNote and note not in patternNotes:
        patternNotes.append(note)
        notes -= 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want

```
if note[0].isupper() and note not in patternNotes:
```

rather than

```
if note[0].isupper() and not in patternNotes:
```

Note the lacking `note` in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `note[0].isupper() and note not in patternNotes:` (notice the second `note` before `not`)

After that your syntax is fine:

```
i = {}
j = {}
print i is not j and j not in {}
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is an infinite loop under certain conditions, like "note in patternNotes".  Move the "notes -= 1" statement outside the if/elif and the problem is solved.